# Fetch id of selected option in dropdown in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model named 'Assessment':

```
class Assessment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assessment_students
  has_many :students, through: :assessment_students
end
```

Join table is:

```
class AssessmentStudent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :assessment
end
```

There is another model:

```
class Classroom < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :classroom_students
 has_many :students, through: :classroom_students
 has_many :assessments
end
```

In show,html.erb of classrooms, I have a dropdown which shows all assessments (generated from assessment table).

Code is:

```
<%= collection_select(:assessment :assessment_id, Assessment.all, :id, :assessment_name , :prompt => true) %>
```

Requirement of the project is: Based on the assessment chosen by the user in the show.html.erb page, we have to show all students details like name etc assigned to that particular assessment. I have stored this data  in  join table 'AssessmentStudent '. However, I am not sure how to pass id from the above collection_select to classroom controller. I have below code:

show.html.erb:

```
<%= collection_select(:assessment :assessment_id, Assessment.all, :id, :assessment_name , :prompt => true) %>

<div id="divResult">
 <% @assessmentstudents1.each do |t| %>
      <% t.assessment_students.each do |record| %>
        <%= record.student_id %>
     <% end %>  
   <% end %>  
</div>
```

classroom controller:

```
def show
   @assessmentstudents1 = Assessment.find(params[:assessment][:assessment_id]).preload(:assessment_students)
end

def classroom_params
  params.require(:classroom).permit(:classroom_name, :classroom_year, :customer_id, :classroom_student, :student_ids => [])
  params.require(:assessment).permit(:assessment_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first recommend to make a change to the controller structure of your application. Because the responsibility of the `show` action of your `ClassroomsController` should be to display the details of the classroom. When you want to show the details of an Assessment, that should be handled by an `AssessmentsController`.

First of all, I'm gonna assume that your `Assessment` model has a `belongs_to :classroom` association. Then I would suggest creating the following structure.

config/routes.rb

```
resources :classrooms
resources :assessments
```

app/views/classrooms/show.html.erb

```
<% @classroom.assessments.each do |assessment| %>
  <%= link_to assessment_name, assessment_path(assessment) %>
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/assessments_controller.rb

```
class AssessmentsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @assessment = Assessment.find(:id)
  end

end
```

app/views/assessments/show.html.erb

```
<h1>Students for <%= @assessment.assessment_name %></h1>
<% @assessment.students.each do |student| %>
  <p><%= student.student_name %></p>
<% end %>

<h2>In classroom:</h2>
<p><%= @assessment.classroom.classroom_name %></p>
```

So to explain what is happening here, we have configured the routes to allow the server to respond to the url `/assessments/:id` which will lead to the `AssessmentsController#show` action being called.

That action is being called when the user clicks on any of the links that we have setup in the `classrooms/show` template. Note that I used individual links for now instead of a select dropdown, because it is easier to setup and understand how it works. And like the previous answer suggested, using a select tag requires a little bit of JavaScript to get working.

And lastly, when the `assessments/show` template is being rendered, it will list out all of the students related to that particular assignment. And I also included which classroom it is assigned to (if my assumption of belongs_to was correct).

On a side note, if your question tag of `ruby-on-rails-3` is correct, then the usage of `params.permit` and `params.require` is invalid, because that is something that was introduced in Rails 4 (unless I'm mistaken). And in any case, you only have to use `permit` when database updates take place, which means the `create` and `update` actions, not `index`, `show`, etc, because it is a way of restricting which changes are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Tag `select` does nothing by itself. So there are two possible options.
The first is wrapping `select` in `form` tag then submitting the form will lead to request. The second is writing a handler using JavaScript which will listen to `select` changes.